# Configure a local proxy via the Docker compose file?

Tags: docker

I have an image that I’ve used for a long time now that works perfectly. It allows me to spin up a new project and via the compose file, I have everything I need to hit the ground running. The one thing I’ve always been frustrated by is that apparent complexity of getting some proxies working for local development.

At the moment I get a web server that will allow me to access the running container via localhost. For my own sanity I’d love to be able to have myproject.test or something along those lines. Is there anyway this can be done via the compose file? I've tried searching for days but I can't seem to find a way to do this but it seems like something that shouldn't be so hard.

My compose file looks like:

```
version: ‘2’

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./docker/webserver
    image: perch
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    env_file:
      - web-variables.env

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --sql_mode=""
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_xxx
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
        mcrypt \
        imagemagick \
        libpng-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        curl \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        libvpx-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-vpx-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        gd \
        curl \
    && a2enmod \
        rewrite \
        ssl \
        actions \
        include \
        cgi \
    && service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot do this *only* by configuring your `docker-compose.yml` (at least, there is no image that I know that makes this possible yet – but would be a cool thing actually!)

What you *can* do is mounting a pre-configured configuration file for your reverse proxy inside the webserver's container and then adapt it to your needs. What you *cannot* do dynamically is making your browser go to your reverse proxy by hitting `http://myproject.test`.* You would have to configure your `/etc/hosts` file for this. Of course, you can do that on your own machine, if this is sufficient for you.

(*) Ok, you *could* do this, but it doesn't seem like a right thing to do, please correct me if you think otherwise.

Comment: I don't mind editing my hosts file, but every search I've done results in some crazy complicated reverse proxy setups. It seems like a lot of work but something that I thought Docker would cater for! I'll try a few more tutorials and if it doesn't work I'll settle for what I have.

Comment: If you just make your `/etc/hosts` file look like this: `127.0.0.1 localhost myproject.test` (just this line, of course there is more in this file), then you can reach your localhost at this address. You can confirm that by `docker run --rm -p 80:80 httpd:alpine` and then `curl myproject.test` from your host – this should return `It works!`. Is this what you want to achieve, basically?